# How to get patterns of groups in Java regex?

Tags: java, regex

Assume that I am given a regex pattern, `whole_pattern`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(whole_pattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
if (m.find()) {
    String s1 = m.group(1);
    String s2 = m.group(2);        
}
```

Obviously, we can get matched string of each group. But can we get the pattern of each group in the `whole_pattern` string? For example if `whole_pattern = (\\d+)(\\w+)`, then patterns of group 1 and group 2 are `\\d+` and `\\w+`, respectively.

Comment: You can parse them out of the string by iterating the characters and counting opening and closing parentheses (taking into account non-capturing groups).

Comment: @AndyTurner: Do we have any automatic way to do this? Also, much effort is needed for manually parsing, considering case of nested patterns.

Comment: if by automatic you mean already implemented, I doubt it. This is a pretty unusual requirement. Nested isn't really much harder.

Comment: perform another *regex* search on `whole_pattern` to get all the strings inside groups `()`

Comment: The problem of implementing a pattern parser is that we cannot know the which group that the pattern belongs to. For example, we do not know `pattern = "\\w+"` in the group 1, 2, or 3 of `whole_pattern = "(\\d+(\\w+)\\d+)(\\d\\w)"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexp for regexp:

```
public void simpleTest() {
    String whole_pattern = "(\\d+)(\\w+)";
    System.out.println(patternGroups(whole_pattern));
}

private List<String> patternGroups(String patternString) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    String pattern = "\\(([^()]+)\\)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    Matcher m = p.matcher(patternString);
    while (m.find()) {
        result.add(m.group(1));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Output of `simpleTest()` call will be:

```
[\d+, \w+]
```

Comment: Yes, it will impose limits on what kind of patterns you can use though

Answer (score -1):

Split your pattern string by ) and remove the first character in each elementh of the resulting array.

Comment: Can we do this with nested patterns?